# Return multiple values with function using Python

Tags: python, function

I have a list of code to update the value of time for each 5 elements. This is the code:

```
msg = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
theta=1
time=4.5

def get_new_theta(msg, theta,time):
    new_theta = [theta]
    new_time = [time]
    for a, b in zip(msg[3::5], msg[4::5]):
        new_theta.append(new_theta[-1] + a + b)
        new_time.append(new_time[-1]+time)
    return new_theta
    return new_time

for i, theta in enumerate(get_new_theta(msg, theta,time)[:-1]):
    for j in range(5):
        print(theta, msg[i*5+j],time)
```

However, I did not get the desired output. The desired output should be:

```
1 1 4.5
1 2 4.5
1 3 4.5
1 4 4.5
1 5 4.5
10 6 9
10 7 9
10 8 9
10 9 9
10 10 9
29 11 13.5
29 12 13.5
29 13 13.5
29 14 13.5
29 15 13.5
```

Need help from this forum. Thank you.

Comment: You have two return statements but only one will ever be reached.

Comment: Use `return new_theta, new_time`

Comment: @ParthS007. I have try it but it is not same as the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_new_theta(msg, theta, time):
    new_theta = [theta]
    new_time = [time]
    for a, b in zip(msg[3::5], msg[4::5]):
        new_theta.append(new_theta[-1] + a + b)
        new_time.append(new_time[-1]+time)
    return new_theta[:-1], new_time[:-1]

msg = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
theta = 1
time = 4.5

for i, (theta, time) in enumerate( zip(*get_new_theta(msg, theta, time)) ):
    for j in range(5):
        print(theta, msg[i*5+j], time)
```

gives:

```
1 1 4.5
1 2 4.5
1 3 4.5
1 4 4.5
1 5 4.5
10 6 9.0
10 7 9.0
10 8 9.0
10 9 9.0
10 10 9.0
29 11 13.5
29 12 13.5
29 13 13.5
29 14 13.5
29 15 13.5
```

`get_new_theta(msg, theta, time)` returns a tuple of the lists `(new_theta, new_time)`. And `zip(*get_new_theta(msg, theta, time))` gives an iterator over tuples `(theta, time)`